# Specific formatting of sequences in YAML

Tags: ruamel.yaml

Is it possible to output sequences with ruamel.yaml in the following format:

```
-
  key1: 1
  key2: 2
  key3: 3
```

instead of standard

```
- key1: 1
  key2: 2
  key3: 3
```

...and this

```
- skills:
    - Python
    - Perl
```

instead of standard...

```
- skills:
  - Python
  - Perl
```

The second example is what `yaml.indent(sequence = 4, offset = 2)` should be for. But then the top-level list also gets indented:

```
  - skills:
      - Python
      - Perl
```

Answer (score 1):

These are essentially two questions: the first on how to prevent
getting the default compact representation and the second on using
different indentations for different sequences.

To start with the first: you can achieve that using the `.compact()` method (make sure you 
have `ruamel.yaml>=0.15.73` installed):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
-
  key1: 1
  key2: 2
  key3: 3
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.compact(seq_map=False)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
-
  key1: 1
  key2: 2
  key3: 3
```

You can also provide `seq_seq=False` as argument to `.compact()` if you don't want compact 
sequences within sequences (looking like `- - abc`)

---

The second is not possible out of the box, as indenting (and
compacting for that matter) is always applied to all sequences
resp. mappings, even to a root level sequence.

The best is to use a transform function:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- skills:
  - Python
  - Perl
"""

def dedent2(s):
    return ''.join([x[2:] if x.startswith('  ') else x for x in s.splitlines(True)])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=dedent2)
```

which gives:

```
- skills:
    - Python
    - Perl
```